# react-native self scrolling effect using scrollview

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am not sure if the heading is accurate but I want to implement something like this in react-native

[image]

Notice how it automatically scrolls for a while when the user scrolls quickly from right to left.

This is what I have

[image]

This is how my code looks like

```js
<ScrollView
  style={{ ...styles.scrollView }}
  horizontal={true}
  contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollViewContainer}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
  {profileData.map((profile, index) => {
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        key={`${index}Profile`}
        onPress={() => setActive(index)}>
        <View style={styles.imageCircle}>
          <ImageCircle uri={profile.path} active={index === active} />
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  })}
</ScrollView>
```

Any idea how I can fix it/apply it in my component? Below are the relevant styles.

```js
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scrollView: {
    height: 100,
  },
  scrollViewContainer: {
    paddingHorizontal: width * 0.5 - width * 0.1,
  },
  imageCircle: {
    width: width * 0.2,
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default styles;
```

Comment: Have a look at [decelerationRate Prop](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#decelerationrate) in ScrollViews. Play around with this for a while. Ping again if it doesn't help.

Comment: @Kartikey Thanks for answering. Default value is normal for `decelerationRate`